# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object Laravel

Tags: laravel, sesiones, users-roles, laravel-livewire

Estuve buscando la solución adecuada a este inconveniente y si bien hay mucha información no me percato como desarrollar la solución.

Me pasa cuando estoy con un usuario logueado y la sesion caduca como puedo direccionar al login en vez de que muestre este error?

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Error producido en:

```
@livewire('panel.zooms-component', ['usuarioid' => Auth::user()->id])
```

utilización:

```
public $usuarioId;

public function mount($usuarioid = '')
{
    $this->usuarioId = $usuarioid;      
}

public function render()
{
    $contactos = Property::with('contactos')->where('user_id', $this->usuarioId)->get();
    // dd($contactos);
    return view('livewire.panel.mis-contactos-component', [
        'contactos' => $contactos
    ]);
}
```

¿Hay una forma en laravel de indicar que cuando caduque la sesion redireccione al usuario a login?

**EDICION**

¿Puede ser así?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

la puedes solucionar en la ruta agregandole el middleware('auth')

Comment: Alguna explicación al respecto?

Comment: Hola Ivan, edite el código, al final puse el mideleware, estaría bien de esa forma?

Comment: Suena a que pudes explicar un poco mas. La idea del sitio es que juntemos conociemiento

Answer (score 0):

La Ruta que esta apuntando a estos (metodos, funciones o controlador) no están bajo un middleware('auth'), implemente un middleware.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function(){
    Route::apiResource('type', TypeController::class);
});
```

este Facade `Auth::user()->id` solo esta habilitado si cumple esto.